# Regression homework problem: statistical significance

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, self-study

I installed the R package AER, from which you get the data `PSID1982`. Then I define this model:

```
data("PSID1982")
set.seed(15606)
selectedobs = sample.int(nrow(PSID1982),size = 400, replace = FALSE)
attach(PSID1982);
experiencesq = experience^2
dgender = 1*(gender=="male")
dmarried = 1*(married=="yes")
dunion = 1*(union=="yes")
dindustry = 1*(industry=="yes")

outreg = lm(log(wage) ~ experience + experiencesq + education + dgender + 
                        dmarried + dunion + dindustry)
summary(outreg);
```

And now I need to find out if the impact of the amount of work `experience` on the `log(wage)` is different for women compared to men, and what do I expect it to be intuitively?

I want to divide the set of data into 2 subsets being men and women and perform a linear regression each dataset, so I do this. but then I get this error message and I don't know how to fix this....

```
outreg = lm(wage~ experience+experiencesq+education+dmarried+dunion+dindustry, 
            subset(PSID1982,gender=="male"))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = wage ~ experience + experiencesq +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'experiencesq')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please (1) edit your question to conform to standard English gramar and usage; (2) format code blocks as code and (3) read the self-study tag and its wiki.

Comment: is it ok now?@user777

Comment: I've made some edits, but you still need to revise the question portion of your post to satisfy the requirements for homework help. Please read the self-study tag and wiki.

Comment: Why are there so many close votes? Because the user has not shown what he/she has tried by himself/herself? (The econometric question itself looks fine to me.)

Comment: Latriuz, take a look at your title; it does not seem to match your actual question and merits an edit.

Comment: @Hardy, is it ok now, can my question not be on hold anymore?

Comment: Decide what your question is - you already have an answer on what approach to take to investigate how the effect of experience on age varies by gender. But you're now asking a programming question about a different approach. Programming questions are off-topic here - but to save time note that you've defined `experiencesq` as vectors & c. outside the `PSID1982` data frame so they won't be included in `subset(PSID1982,gender=="male")` & therefore the "different variable lengths" error message.

Comment: @Scortchi, ok. then i do this and it still say this... > 
    newdata <- subset(PSID1982, gender=="male",
    +                   select=experience:wage)
    > mymodel1 = lm(wage~  
    experience+experiencesq+education+dmarried+dunion+dindustry, 
    data=newdata)
    Error in model.frame.default(formula = wage ~ experience +             experiencesq +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'experiencesq')
  In addition: Warning message:
  'newdata' had 359 rows but variables found have 400 rows. And i cant understand how to put this code into special letters like you do ffs

Comment: Either (1) add the derived variables as columns of the data frame *before* subsetting it, or (2) subset *each* of them when performing the regression. (Though it'd be useful to read up on factors & the formula interface in R - `relevel` & `I` would probably save you some work over time.) Use the backtick - ` - for inline formatting of code. Once you've got a regression model for each sex consider how this approach compares with @Michael's.

Comment: @Scortchi, jesus man im sry to bother you but im really stuck. I dont know how to do it. Its the last exercise i need to complete, could you give me the code and explain to me how it works so i can understand  it and can reproduce it myself when i get this question on my exam? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the context of linear regression if you are looking to see if an additional year of experience impacts wages differently for men and women you want to use an interaction term. To see this write the model as:
$$ \log(wage) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 exper + \beta_2 gender + \beta_3 exper \times gender + u$$
where $gender = 1$ if the person is female. I have dropped additional terms for simplicity. The partial effect of experience on log wage is given by 
$$ \frac{\partial \log(wage)}{\partial exper} = \beta_1 + \beta_3 gender$$
So if the person is a female the effect is $\beta_1 + \beta_3$ and for a male it is $\beta_1$. This means that the difference in the effect for females and males is $\beta_3$. You will want to perform the normal hypothesis testing on $\beta_3$ to determine if there is a statistically different effect by gender.

In your model when you add $exper^2$ you will need to interact both $exper$ and $exper^2$ with $gender$, and go through and find the proper marginal effects.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? if the person is male the effect is β1+β3 and if the person is male the effect is β1?@Michael

Comment: cant i do this easily with anova somehow? i think we need to use that for this exercise but im not sure @michael

Comment: In my answer I defined gender to be 1 for females, where you defined it be 1 for males. So yes the way you are defining the variables it would be $\beta_1$ for females and $\beta_1 + \beta_3$ for males. With regards to anova I am not familiar enough with to to speak about how you may approach this type of problem.